# Flutter NoSuchMethodError: The method 'toDate' was called on null

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, timestamp, stream-builder

An exception was thrown: `NoSuchMethodError: The method 'toDate' was called on null`.

**Exception:**

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FOUNDATION LIBRARY ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for TextEditingController:
setState() called after dispose(): _CommentsState#74ccc(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in
the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error
can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose()
callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling
setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is
retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory
leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      State.setState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1137:9)
#1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1172:6)
#2      _CommentsState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:anime_space_app/widgets/comments.dart:33:41)
#3      ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:308:24)
#4      ValueNotifier.value= (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:412:5)
#5      TextEditingController.value= (package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:154:11)
#6      EditableTextState._value= (package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:2161:23)
#7      EditableTextState._formatAndSetValue (package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:2540:5)
#8      EditableTextState.userUpdateTextEditingValue (package:flutter/src/widgets/editable_text.dart:2769:5)
#9      RenderEditable._setTextEditingValue (package:flutter/src/rendering/editable.dart:735:27)
#10     RenderEditable._setSelection (package:flutter/src/rendering/editable.dart:755:5)
#11     RenderEditable.selectPositionAt (package:flutter/src/rendering/editable.dart:1974:5)
#12     RenderEditable.selectPosition (package:flutter/src/rendering/editable.dart:1950:5)
#13     TextSelectionGestureDetectorBuilder.onSingleTapUp (package:flutter/src/widgets/text_selection.dart:1158:26)  
#14     _TextFieldSelectionGestureDetectorBuilder.onSingleTapUp (package:flutter/src/material/text_field.dart:89:11) 
#15     _TextSelectionGestureDetectorState._handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/widgets/text_selection.dart:1511:29)    
#16     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:611:57)
#17     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:198:24)
#18     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:611:11)
#19     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:298:5)
#20     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:269:7)
#21     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:157:27)
#22     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:443:20)
#23     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:419:22)
#24     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:322:11)
#25     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
#26     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
#27     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
#28     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
#32     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:170:10)
#33     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:331:7)
#34     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:94:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)

The TextEditingController sending notification was:
  TextEditingController#722ea(TextEditingValue(text: ┤├, selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset:
  0, affinity: TextAffinity.downstream, isDirectional: false), composing: TextRange(start: -1, end:
  -1)))
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
D/InputMethodManager(21258): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@456f89[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(21258): getNavigationBarColor() -15130582
V/InputMethodManager(21258): Starting input: tba=site.animslash.app ic=io.flutter.plugin.editing.InputConnectionAdaptor@6a46c51 mNaviBarColor -15130582 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager(21258): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager(21258): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport(21258): Input channel constructed: fd=159
D/InputTransport(21258): Input channel destroyed: fd=187
D/InputMethodManager(21258): SSI - flag : 0 Pid : 21258 view : site.animslash.app
D/InputMethodManager(21258): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@456f89[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(21258): getNavigationBarColor() -15130582
E/SpannableStringBuilder(21258): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(21258): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(21258): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder(21258): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
D/ViewRootImpl@d406a90[MainActivity](21258): MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2960) ci=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 1032) vi=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 1032) or=١
D/ViewRootImpl@d406a90[MainActivity](21258): Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1440,2960] new=[0,0][1440,2960] result=0x1 
surface={valid=true 497100464128} changed=false
D/InputMethodManager(21258): SSI - flag : 0 Pid : 21258 view : site.animslash.app
D/InputMethodManager(21258): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@456f89[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(21258): getNavigationBarColor() -15130582

Another exception was thrown: setState() called after dispose(): _CommentsState#74ccc(lifecycle state: defunct, not  
mounted)

Another exception was thrown: setState() called after dispose(): _CommentsState#74ccc(lifecycle state: defunct, not  
mounted)
D/InputMethodManager(21258): SSI - flag : 0 Pid : 21258 view : site.animslash.app
D/InputMethodManager(21258): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@456f89[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(21258): getNavigationBarColor() -15130582

Another exception was thrown: setState() called after dispose(): _CommentsState#74ccc(lifecycle state: defunct, not  
mounted)
D/InputMethodManager(21258): SSI - flag : 0 Pid : 21258 view : site.animslash.app
D/InputMethodManager(21258): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@456f89[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(21258): getNavigationBarColor() -15130582
D/InputMethodManager(21258): SSI - flag : 0 Pid : 21258 view : site.animslash.app
D/InputMethodManager(21258): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@456f89[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(21258): getNavigationBarColor() -15130582

Another exception was thrown: setState() called after dispose(): _CommentsState#74ccc(lifecycle state: defunct, not  
mounted)
D/ViewRootImpl@d406a90[MainActivity](21258): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@d406a90[MainActivity](21258): ViewPostIme pointer 1

Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'toDate' was called on null.

Another exception was thrown: setState() called after dispose(): _CommentsState#74ccc(lifecycle state: defunct, not  
mounted)
I/TextInputPlugin(21258): Composing region changed by the framework. Restarting the input method.
D/InputMethodManager(21258): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@456f89[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(21258): getNavigationBarColor() -15130582
V/InputMethodManager(21258): Starting input: tba=site.animslash.app ic=io.flutter.plugin.editing.InputConnectionAdaptor@67a2caf mNaviBarColor -15130582 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager(21258): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager(21258): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport(21258): Input channel constructed: fd=160
D/InputTransport(21258): Input channel destroyed: fd=159
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(21258): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(21258): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
E/SpannableStringBuilder(21258): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
I/chatty  (21258): uid=10334(site.animslash.app) identical 2 lines
E/SpannableStringBuilder(21258): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'toDate' was called on null.
```

**Source Code:**

```
class Comments extends StatefulWidget {   Comments({this.title});   final String? title;   @override   State<Comments> createState() =>
_CommentsState(); }

class _CommentsState extends State<Comments> {   @override   void initState() {
    getcurrentuser();
    CommentController.addListener(() => setState(() {}));

    super.initState();   }

  void getcurrentuser() {
    try {
      final user = _auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        signinUser = user;
        print(signinUser.email);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }   }

  @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final CmID = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Comments')
        .doc('${widget.title}')
        .collection('Comments')
        .doc()
        .id;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: kBackgroundColor,
                border: Border(
                  top: BorderSide(
                    color: kBackgroundColor,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: CommentController,
                        validator: (val) {
                          if (val!.isEmpty || val.length <= 2) {
                            return "الرجاء ادخال تعليق صحيح";
                          } else {
                            return null;
                          }
                        },
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.comment, color: Colors.white),
                          labelText: 'ادخل تعليقك',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          prefixStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          iconColor: Colors.blue,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10,
                            horizontal: 20,
                          ),
                          prefixIconColor: Colors.blue,
                          suffixIcon: CommentController.text.isEmpty
                              ? Container(
                                  width: 0,
                                )
                              : IconButton(
                                  splashRadius: 22,
                                  onPressed: () => CommentController.clear(),
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                                ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                          ),
                          disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          focusColor: Colors.blue,
                          hoverColor: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                    TextButton(
                      style: ButtonStyle(),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (CommentController.text.isEmpty ||
                            CommentController.text.length < 3) {
                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                            msg: 'يجب على تعليقك ان يكون حرفين او اكثر',
                            backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
                          );
                        } else {
                          final commentid = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection('Comments')
                              .doc(widget.title)
                              .collection('Comments')
                              .doc();

                          final json = {
                            'id': commentid.id,
                            'sender': signinUser.displayName,
                            'img': signinUser.photoURL,
                            'time': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                            'text': CommentController.text,
                          };

                          await commentid.set(json);

                          CommentController.clear();
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'ارسال',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 14,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          CommentsStreamBuilder(
            title: '${widget.title}',
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );   } }



class CommentsLine extends StatelessWidget {
  CommentsLine(
      {required this.time,
      this.title,
      this.img,
      this.text,
      this.sender,
      required this.isMe});
  final String? title;
  final Timestamp time;
  final String? sender;
  final String? text;
  final bool isMe;

  final String? img;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime minAgo = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(minutes: 1));
    DateTime secAgo = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    DateTime dayAgo = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1));
    DateTime monAgo = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 30));
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8), color: kBackgroundColor),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      '$sender',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      timeago.format(time.toDate(), locale: 'ar'),
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 12),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 20,
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage('$img'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                '$text',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CommentsStreamBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  CommentsStreamBuilder({this.title});
  final String? title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore
          .collection('Comments')
          .doc('$title')
          .collection('Comments')
          .orderBy('time')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        List<CommentsLine> commentsWidget = [];

        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
            ),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.data?.docs.isEmpty != false) {
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  'images/cry.gif',
                  height: 110,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Text(
                  "لاتوجد تعليقات",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
        final messages = snapshot.data!.docs.reversed;
        for (var message in messages) {
          final messagetext = message.get('text');
          final messgaesender = message.get('sender');
          final messgaeimg = message.get('img');
          final datatime = message.get('time');
          final currentUser = signinUser.displayName;

          final commentWidget = CommentsLine(
            sender: messgaesender,
            time: datatime,
            img: messgaeimg,
            text: messagetext,
            isMe: currentUser == messgaesender,
            title: title,
          );
          commentsWidget.add(commentWidget);
        }

        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            reverse: false,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
            children: commentsWidget,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code of the file where the error occurred - `_CommentsState`?

Comment: Where do I get it?

Comment: You Mean This?

  void initState() {
    getcurrentuser();
    CommentController.addListener(() => setState(() {}));

    super.initState();
  }

Comment: I added it """"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if `time` is null or not. check the code below.

```dart
class Comments extends StatefulWidget {   Comments({this.title});   final String? title;   @override   State<Comments> createState() =>
_CommentsState(); }

class _CommentsState extends State<Comments> {   @override   void initState() {
    getcurrentuser();
    CommentController.addListener(() => setState(() {}));

    super.initState();   }

  void getcurrentuser() {
    try {
      final user = _auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        signinUser = user;
        print(signinUser.email);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }   }

  @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final CmID = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Comments')
        .doc('${widget.title}')
        .collection('Comments')
        .doc()
        .id;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: kBackgroundColor,
                border: Border(
                  top: BorderSide(
                    color: kBackgroundColor,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: CommentController,
                        validator: (val) {
                          if (val!.isEmpty || val.length <= 2) {
                            return "الرجاء ادخال تعليق صحيح";
                          } else {
                            return null;
                          }
                        },
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.comment, color: Colors.white),
                          labelText: 'ادخل تعليقك',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          prefixStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          iconColor: Colors.blue,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10,
                            horizontal: 20,
                          ),
                          prefixIconColor: Colors.blue,
                          suffixIcon: CommentController.text.isEmpty
                              ? Container(
                                  width: 0,
                                )
                              : IconButton(
                                  splashRadius: 22,
                                  onPressed: () => CommentController.clear(),
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                                ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                          ),
                          disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          focusColor: Colors.blue,
                          hoverColor: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                    TextButton(
                      style: ButtonStyle(),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (CommentController.text.isEmpty ||
                            CommentController.text.length < 3) {
                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                            msg: 'يجب على تعليقك ان يكون حرفين او اكثر',
                            backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
                          );
                        } else {
                          final commentid = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection('Comments')
                              .doc(widget.title)
                              .collection('Comments')
                              .doc();

                          final json = {
                            'id': commentid.id,
                            'sender': signinUser.displayName,
                            'img': signinUser.photoURL,
                            'time': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                            'text': CommentController.text,
                          };

                          await commentid.set(json);

                          CommentController.clear();
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'ارسال',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 14,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          CommentsStreamBuilder(
            title: '${widget.title}',
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );   } }



class CommentsLine extends StatelessWidget {
  CommentsLine(
      {required this.time,
      this.title,
      this.img,
      this.text,
      this.sender,
      required this.isMe});
  final String? title;
  final Timestamp time;
  final String? sender;
  final String? text;
  final bool isMe;

  final String? img;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime minAgo = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(minutes: 1));
    DateTime secAgo = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    DateTime dayAgo = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1));
    DateTime monAgo = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 30));
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8), color: kBackgroundColor),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      '$sender',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    Text(
                     time != null ?  timeago.format(time.toDate(), locale: 'ar': ""), // here check if time is null or not 
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70, fontSize: 12),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 20,
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage('$img'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                '$text',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CommentsStreamBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  CommentsStreamBuilder({this.title});
  final String? title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore
          .collection('Comments')
          .doc('$title')
          .collection('Comments')
          .orderBy('time')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        List<CommentsLine> commentsWidget = [];

        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
            ),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.data?.docs.isEmpty != false) {
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  'images/cry.gif',
                  height: 110,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Text(
                  "لاتوجد تعليقات",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
        final messages = snapshot.data!.docs.reversed;
        for (var message in messages) {
          final messagetext = message.get('text');
          final messgaesender = message.get('sender');
          final messgaeimg = message.get('img');
          final datatime = message.get('time');
          final currentUser = signinUser.displayName;

          final commentWidget = CommentsLine(
            sender: messgaesender,
            time: datatime,
            img: messgaeimg,
            text: messagetext,
            isMe: currentUser == messgaesender,
            title: title,
          );
          commentsWidget.add(commentWidget);
        }

        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            reverse: false,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
            children: commentsWidget,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem could be you do not clear your resources right. Inside the `initState` method, you have something like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
  getcurrentuser();

  CommentController.addListener(() => setState(() {})); // This causes the issue
 
  super.initState();
}
```

The problem is that the `addListener` callback is executed even after the `_CommentsState` is unmounted. Meaning, when you add the listener, you should remove it later as well.

You can do it this way:

```
class _CommentsState extends State<Comments> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState(); // Notice I moved this up as well
    
    getcurrentuser();

    CommentController.addListener(_updateState); // Add listener on init
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    CommentController.removeListener(_updateState); // Remove listener on dispose

    super.dispose();
  }

  void _updateState() => setState(() {});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}
```